# Fongo - OperationExecutor not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, fongo

I would like to use fongo 2.0.x in my Spring boot application, but I getting errror

```
Error:(23, 44) java: cannot access com.mongodb.operation.OperationExecutor
class file for com.mongodb.operation.OperationExecutor not found
```

Here is my AbstractMongoConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo")
public class MongoDbConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "demo";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new Fongo(getDatabaseName()).getMongo(); //this line throws the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is not complete. You need to actually provide the code which actually "throws" the error (specify which line that error message maps to)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Fongo documentation](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo#implementation-details):

> It has a "provided" dependency on the mongo-java-driver and was tested with 2.13.0 and 3.0.1.

So Fongo wants `mongo-java-driver` on the classpath, and I'm guessing you don't have it (or at least not in the `test` scope).

So make sure the following is in your build script:

For Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

For Gradle:

```
testCompile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.4.1'
```